# Starting indexing at 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, index-error

I am not able to initialize the array with starting index 1. I used both insert an append, and I want the index to begin with 1 and not 0:

```
n=int(input('enter '))
array=[]
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(i)
    element=int(input('element '))
    array.insert(i,element)
    #array.append(element)
    print(i,array[i])
```

This gives an `IndexError` exception at `print(i,array[i])`: `list index out of range.`

Comment: Arrays always start at 0. You could only create one additional item and ignore the 0th item.

Comment: can you just use `for i in range(n):...`?

Comment: You have to fit index, which is flexible, to array, which is predefined. No logically need doing not so.

Comment: What is the best naming for an index (willingly) starting at 1? To make it clear to the users of this variable?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have that choice. Python indexing starts at 0, and is not configurable.

You can just *subtract 1* from your indices when indexing:

```
array.insert(i - 1, element)  # but better just use array.append(element)
print(i, array[i - 1])
```

or (more wasteful), start your list with a dummy value at index 0:

```
array = [None]
```

at which point the next index used will be 1.

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!